# fill dropdown menu with my data from database always empty

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to fill dropdown menu with my data from database. But I have empty fields without any data and without errors in console. What am I droing wrong?

I am sending data as json and get it in angularjs.

There is my DB file in php. ( name = usersDB.php )

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db");

if(!$con){
    die('something wrong '.mysqli_error());
}

//echo ('test' . $_GET['action']);
switch($_GET['action'])  {
    case 'get_Logins_info' :
        get_Logins_info(); 
        break;

}

function get_Logins_info(){
    $qry = mysqli_query('SELECT * from login');

    echo("test");

    $data = array();
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $data[] = array(
                    "id"    => $rows['id'],
                    "name"      => $rows['name']
                    );
    }

    print_r(json_encode($data));
    return json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

My table login looks like:

> id name username password

Angular part

```
        $scope.getLogins = function() {
            $http.get('forms/usersDB.php?action=get_Logins_info')
                .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.chooseLogins = data;
                    console.log('Retrieved data from server');
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
                    console.log(data, status);
                });
        };

        $scope.getLogins();
```

html

```
                <md-select ng-model="login" >
                    <md-option ng-repeat="logins in chooseLogins" ng-value="logins.id">{{logins.name}}</md-option>
                 </md-select>
```

I have dropdown list but is empty.

What console say?

```
Retrieved data from server
(index):118 Object {data: "test[]", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: Objectdata: "test[]"headers: (name)status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
(index):122 Error in retrieving data from server
(index):123 undefined undefined
```

Everything looks ok no errors but is empty.

Comment: Are you sure you have data in you table? The output suggests the table `login` is empty

Comment: try to echo the result of the php file inisde a little html page and let me know if there is an empty array or not.

Comment: if you comment out the `echo` and the `print_r`, does that help? I wonder if the output is messing up the response.

Comment: @BizzyBon If I uncomment echo I got: Retrieved data from server
(index):116 Object {data: Array[0], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: Objectdata: Array[0]headers: (name)status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
(index):119 Error in retrieving data from server
(index):120 undefined undefined there is array[0]

Comment: @madshvero yes I am 100% sure cause I am using also this table to login form.

Comment: First thing please update your mysqli_query! The query should be passed one connection object. If you are saying there is data in the table then try printing it in the console. If you get the result then check with your angular data object whether that is passed right.!

Comment: @Abizz Check my answer please with fixed php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't passing the database connection on this line:

```
$qry = mysqli_query('SELECT * from login');
```

Change it to:

```
$qry = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * from login');
```

Comment: Changed still nothing. Current console log
Retrieved data from server  index.php:115:29
Object { data: Array[0], status: 200, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" }  index.php:116:29
Error in retrieving data from server  index.php:119:29
undefined undefined

Comment: So take angular out of the equation for a minute.  Ensure your `print_r` statement is not commented out, and just go to your page `usersDB.php?action=get_Logins_info`

Comment: See what the output is.

Comment: maybe add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top, just for fun.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); shows nothing and usersDB.php?action=get_Logins_info shows two brackets []

Comment: please get the code inside the function, put in a single file, and execute it and echo the result. And let us see these results.

Comment: I forgot to add my connection to function. Now I am getting something like ArrayArrayArray 

But when I do printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["name"]); it works and I have objects. How to put it to array

Comment: @BizzyBob Check my answer with fixed php

Answer (score 0):

Edit with fix.

There is my php.

```
switch($_GET['action'])  {
    case 'get_Logins_info' :
        get_Logins_info($con,$row); 
        break;

}

function get_Logins_info($con){

    $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from login"); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $data[] = array(  
                        "id"    => $row['id'],
                        "name"      => $row['name']
                     );
        //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["name"]); - This print proper data
       // print_r($data); - This print table in way like [0] Array [1] Proper data [2] Array [3] Proper data


    }


     print_r(json_encode($data)); // this print Array[2]
    return json_encode($data);


}
```

But I still have empty select fields. I think that is problem with my html

Angular

```
 $scope.ChooseLogins = [];

                $scope.getLogins = function() {
                    $http.get('forms/usersDB.php?action=get_Logins_info')
                        .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope.chooseLogins = data;
                            console.log('Retrieved data from server');
                            console.log(data);
                        })
                        .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
                            console.log(data, status);
                        });
                };

                $scope.getLogins();
```

When I did something like myaddress.com/forms/usersDB.php?action=get_Logins_info
I have my rows from database

html ( I have two options but without data )

```
<md-select ng-model="newTask.login" >
                            <md-option ng-repeat="logins in ChooseLogins" ng-value="logins.id">{{logins.name}}</md-option>
                         </md-select>
```